# NSUserDefauts - Only new NSStrings not appearing in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Before explaining the issue, I want to mention I have already tried solutions from these questions:

1. [Xcode not building app with changes incorporated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493328/xcode-not-building-app-with-changes-incorporated)
2. [Why can't I delete files from my XCode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875836/why-cant-i-delete-files-from-my-xcode-project)
3. [XCode simulator is not displaying latest changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971230/xcode-simulator-is-not-displaying-latest-changes)

I have archived my app and it is now submitted in the App Store, but now I cannot make the changes I need in order to provide sound updates. The app provides statistics for different topics, as well as MLA/APA citations and a web view of that source. The code is structured this way:

A TopicViewController.m holds NSString variables for each statistic, citation, and source URL. IBActions related to specific topic UIButtons, like Cybersecurity for example, set the content of each NSString variable. Finally, I save the data for all stats, citations and URLs in NSUserDefaults and synchronize them. **THESE IBACTIONS ARE WHERE I ADD NEW CONTENT**.

sample code (the actual number of strings is very very large):

```
@implementation StatsViewController

NSString *cybersecStatistic1;
NSString *cybersecStatistic2;
NSString *cybersecStatistic3;
NSString *cybersecStatistic1CitationMLA;
NSString *cybersecStatistic1CitationAPA;
NSString *cybersecStatistic2CitationMLA;
NSString *cybersecStatistic2CitationAPA;
NSString *cybersecStatistic3CitationMLA;
NSString *cybersecStatistic3CitationAPA;
NSString *cybersecStatistic1Source;
NSString *cybersecStatistic2Source;
NSString *cybersecStatistic3Source;

-(IBAction)cybersecurityGo:(id)sender {
    cybersecStatistic1 = @"\"In 2015, nearly 20% of global companies implemented a cybersecurity budget between $1 million and $4.9 million.\" (PricewaterhouseCoopers survey)";
    cybersecStatistic2 = @"The average annual number of cybersecurity incidents is 80-90 million. There was a 38% increase in such incidents from 2014-2015.";
    cybersecStatistic3 = @"USA: Over 36% of people who share passwords have shared the password associated with their banking account.";

    cybersecStatistic1CitationAPA = @"Penguin Strategies. (2016, January 17). Top Cybersecurity Statistics for 2016 - Cyber Security Marketing Blog. Retrieved April 16, 2016, from http://www.marketingcyber.com/2016-cybersecurity-statistics/";
    cybersecStatistic2CitationAPA = @"Smith, C. (2016, January 20). 34 Amazing Cybersecurity Statistics. Retrieved April 16, 2016, from http://expandedramblings.com/index.php/cybersecurity-statistics/";
    cybersecStatistic3CitationAPA = @"Norton by Symantec. (1995-2016). Norton Cybersecurity Insights Report. Retrieved April 16, 2016, from https://us.norton.com/cyber-security-insights";

    cybersecStatistic1CitationMLA = @"\"Top Cybersecurity Statistics for 2016 - Cyber Security Marketing Blog.\"Cyber Security Marketing Blog. Penguin Strategies, 17 Jan. 2016. Web. 16 Apr. 2016.";
    cybersecStatistic2CitationMLA = @"Smith, Craig. \"34 Amazing Cybersecurity Statistics.\" DMR. DMR, 20 Jan. 2016. Web. 16 Apr. 2016.";
    cybersecStatistic3CitationMLA = @"\"Norton Cybersecurity Insights Report.\" 2016. Norton by Symantec, 1995-2016. Web. 16 Apr. 2016.";

    cybersecStatistic1Source = @"http://www.marketingcyber.com/2016-cybersecurity-statistics/";
    cybersecStatistic2Source = @"http://expandedramblings.com/index.php/cybersecurity-statistics/";
    cybersecStatistic3Source = @"https://us.norton.com/cyber-security-insights";

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic1 forKey:@"statistic1"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic2 forKey:@"statistic2"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic3 forKey:@"statistic3"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic1CitationMLA forKey:@"statistic1CitationMLA"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic1CitationAPA forKey:@"statistic1CitationAPA"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic2CitationMLA forKey:@"statistic2CitationMLA"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic2CitationAPA forKey:@"statistic2CitationAPA"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic3CitationMLA forKey:@"statistic3CitationMLA"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic3CitationAPA forKey:@"statistic3CitationAPA"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic1Source forKey:@"statistic1Source"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic2Source forKey:@"statistic2Source"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: cybersecStatistic3Source forKey:@"statistic3Source"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Tapping a topic button takes you to the next screen, StatsViewController. It's implementation file receives the NSUserDefaults and displays the appropriate statistics. IBActions related to each statistic UIButton set the “route” for the next screen in order to display the correct citations. **THIS IS WHERE SOMETHING SEEMS TO GO WRONG BECAUSE THE CITATIONS ARE DISPLAYED FOR THE LAST STAT I VIEWED (NEVER THE NEWLY ADDED STAT'S CITATION)--> I FIXED THIS ISSUE BEFORE BY CHANGING MY `ViewDidLoad` to a `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` in CitationViewController which I will explain next**.

```
@implementation StatsViewController

NSString *whichStat;

NSString *strStat1;
NSString *strStat2;
NSString *strStat3;

-(IBAction)stat1Go:(id)sender {
    whichStat = @"stat1Route";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:whichStat forKey:@"activeStat"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
-(IBAction)stat2Go:(id)sender {
    whichStat = @"stat2Route";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:whichStat forKey:@"activeStat"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
-(IBAction)stat3Go:(id)sender {
    whichStat = @"stat3Route";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:whichStat forKey:@"activeStat"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    whichStat = nil;
    strStat1 = nil;
    strStat2 = nil;
    strStat3 = nil;

    strStat1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic1"];
    strStat2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic2"];
    strStat3 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic3"];

    [_stat1 setTitle:strStat1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_stat2 setTitle:strStat2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_stat3 setTitle:strStat3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if ([strStat1  isEqual: @"more stats to come"]) {
        _stat1.enabled = false;
    }
    else {
        _stat1.enabled = true;
    }
    if ([strStat2  isEqual: @"more stats to come"]) {
        _stat2.enabled = false;
    }
    else {
        _stat2.enabled = true;
    }
    if ([strStat3  isEqual: @"more stats to come"]) {
        _stat3.enabled = false;
    }
    else {
        _stat3.enabled = true;
    }
```

Tapping a statistic button take you to the CitationViewController, which displays the APA and MLA citations. **THE CITATIONS FOR NEWLY ADDED STRINGS (SINCE APP STORE SUBMISSION) ARE NOT CORRECTLY LOADED IN THE** `ViewWillLayoutSubviews`.

```
@implementation CiteViewController

NSString *citeStatPath;

NSString *citeUsingMLA;
NSString *citeUsingAPA;

NSString *sourceWebSite;

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

citeStatPath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"activeStat"];

    if ([citeStatPath  isEqualToString: @"stat1Route"]) {
        citeUsingMLA = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic1CitationMLA"];
        citeUsingAPA = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic1CitationAPA"];

        [_citeMLA setTitle:citeUsingMLA forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_citeAPA setTitle:citeUsingAPA forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if ([citeStatPath isEqualToString:@"stat2Route"]) {
        citeUsingMLA = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic2CitationMLA"];
        citeUsingAPA = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic2CitationAPA"];

        [_citeMLA setTitle:citeUsingMLA forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_citeAPA setTitle:citeUsingAPA forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        citeUsingMLA = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic3CitationMLA"];
        citeUsingAPA = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic3CitationAPA"];

        [_citeMLA setTitle:citeUsingMLA forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_citeAPA setTitle:citeUsingAPA forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Tapping a citation button takes you to the UIWebView which gets the URL from an NSUserDefault established and saved in TopicViewController.m. **THE CORRECT WEBSITE ALSO DOES NOT APPEAR**.

```
@implementation SourceViewController

NSString *srcStatPath;

NSString *webSite;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    srcStatPath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"activeStat"];

    if ([srcStatPath  isEqualToString: @"stat1Route"]) {
        webSite = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic1Source"];
    }
    else if ([srcStatPath isEqualToString:@"stat2Route"]) {
        webSite = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic2Source"];
    }
    else {
        webSite = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"statistic3Source"];
    }

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webSite];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_source loadRequest:request];
}
```

**This issue occurs on iPhone Simulator and my own iOS device (iPhone 6- version 9.3.2).**

Thank you in advance for the help. I am quite stuck!

Comment: The real question is why on earth are you using NSUserDefaults to pass data between view controllers?  Why don't you just pass the strings or a data model object directly?

Comment: Being honest, that's the only way I knew to share data with different view controllers/ classes. I thought you can't just pass a string, that's wrong? Also, I don't know what you mean by "data model object." Perhaps, I would need to explain my Interface Builder setup, but this is the only way I personally discovered to be possible. I'd love to know a different way.@Paulw11

Comment: Well, normally you would create an object that as properties, such as `statistic` `citation` and `source` and then you can create an instance of this object and assign it's properties.  Then you can just assign this object instance to a property of your destination view controller and it can access the values.  How do you present your `CiteViewController` ? Using a segue?  By implementing the `prepareForSegue` function in your `StatsViewController` you can get a reference to the destination view controller that is about to be presented (your `CiteViewController` instance) and set properties

Comment: Have a look at this - http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: I present my CiteViewController with a seque from buttons in StatViewController. Then, I load the NSUserDefaults into variables within the ViewWillLayoutSubviews and then assign those variables to the stat buttons text. Your way seems 10x better. With very large amounts of data, is it feasible to completely shift my program over to this method of passing data via prepareForSegue methods? @Paulw11

Comment: Yes.  The method I have described is the standard way you would do this.  Also you would typically perform access passed data in `viewWillAppear` not `viewWillLayoutSubviews` as the former method is called once-per-view while `viewWillLayoutSubviews` will be called many times (eg. device rotation)

Comment: You're a big help @Paulw11. I'm fairly new to the world of mobile, particularly iOS. Thanks a ton.